# Is putting my SO profile and reputations on my CV or Resume useful?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Let's say I don't really have so many reputations like above 1k. Should I put my SO profile and my reputations on my CV or Resume?

Is it useful for the employer to know more about me? Or It is just a waste of paper?

Comment: Not sure how that would help you -- reputation score is a subject of change, your CV information will likely get irrelevant soon enough. Perhaps a link to your profile would be better suited.

Comment: Related: [Has anyone ever mentioned their Stack Overflow profile on their CV?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202275/294055)

Comment: Also, if I were an employer and had a link to your SO profile, I'd be more interested in the technology areas you have experience with. Non-established users would usually have more questions than answers related to the technologies they use, and usually these display the stuff you don't know. In my opinion, a SO profile complements a CV well if the user is established with giving some good answers and thus displaying what he does know.

Comment: Also related: [Should I include a link to my Stack Overflow profile on my résumé?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100217/294055)

Comment: This seems to be a question for [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com). Like [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34523/can-your-stack-overflow-careers-profile-be-used-as-an-official-resume) or [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/is-stack-exchange-use-a-valuable-skill-on-my-cv) or [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119745/a-decent-stack-exchange-score-for-resume).

Answer (score -46):

We should think that Stack Overflow is one of the social media like Facebook or Twitter. But it is more technical and proved that you participated actively online.

If you include like a proof in CV, you need spend more time to make your Stack Overflow account look more professional.

Comment: _"We should think that Stack Overflow is one of the social media like Facebook or Twitter."_ No. SO isn't anything like "social media". SO is a site for _quality Q/A_. "Social interaction" is completely irrelevant / off-topic here.

Comment: Just because something is accessible through the web and visited by many people does not make it social media. Please, follow the tour and read through the help center to learn what Stack Overflow is and how you should and should not use it.

Comment: it's hilarious that SO is in a panic that it be referred to as a social media.   :)

Comment: SO is very much a social media. Even if main Q/A isn't intended for that use, comments, chat and meta are heavily used for that purpose. Just look at all the pointless arguments last few years.